# pycountry | extract values or convert Country object to iterable

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, pycountry-convert

How can I **extract** values in Country object or **convert to an iterable**?

Maybe specicially this isn't possible.

Goal: lookup a country code using `alpha_2` param and extract all values.

---

**Usage**

```
pip install pycountry
```

```py
import pycountry

pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2='DE')
>>> Country(alpha_2='DE', alpha_3='DEU', flag='', name='Germany', numeric='276', official_name='Federal Republic of Germany')
```

---

**Attempt**

```py
list(pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2='DE'))
```

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-5d8d83cf3b5c> in <module>
----> 1 list(pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2='DE'))

TypeError: 'Country' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get()` is correct, but you don't convert it into a list. You can get hold of the country with `.get()` and a known attribute, then use dot notation to get the other attributes. E.g.: `country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2='DE')` then `country.name` will get you 'Germany', `country.alpha_3` will get you the alpha3 code for Germany (which is 'DEU'), etc.